# How to calculate hours passed since selected dates

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I would like to do a **SELECT** and receive the number of hours passed since the selected dates as the result of the query. The following code gives me the error: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, dCreated, NOW()) AS hrsAgo FROM ...
```

What do I miss here? My guess would be the *dCreated* as it would refer to the column name, but I'm unable to find the right syntax.

Comment: DATEDIFF() calculates the difference between 2 dates in days. Use TIMESTAMPDIFF(). And always look at Manual Reference for the function description firstly...

Comment: @Akina Sorry, but this is not really answering my question, and also the first parameter of DATEDIFF defines the unit of measure, it is not only for difference in days, see [link](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp)

Comment: If so then look carefully a) what DBMS are you using b) what DBMS is described by the link... PS. Never refer to the site other than official documentation.

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: W3Schools? Seriously?  Friends don't let friends ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you want [TIMESTAMPDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) for this. [DATEDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) does something else.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, dCreated, NOW()) AS hrsAgo FROM ...
```